# T-SQL : execution of stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a procedure which is supposed to save data into a temporary table and at the end of it delete the old records and insert the new ones into the real table.

The end of the procedure is as follows:

```
...
--THIS SELECT HAS THE CORRECT DATA
SELECT * FROM @NewTempTable;

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    --DELETE OLD COMPONENTS
    DELETE FROM AlteracaoEngenharia.hComponents 
    WHERE Id IN (SELECT C.Id  
                 FROM AlteracaoEngenharia.hComponents AS C
                 JOIN AlteracaoEngenharia.hEngineeringChanges AS EC ON C.EngineeringChangeId = EC.Id
                 WHERE C.Name NOT LIKE '%(Manual)%' AND EC.State LIKE 'Aberto');

    INSERT INTO AlteracaoEngenharia.hComponents (Name, OldQuantity, Quantity, CDP, Value, Type, EngineeringChangeId)
        (SELECT 
             Name, OldQuantity, Quantity, CDP, Value, Type, EngineeringChangeId 
         FROM 
             @NewTempTable);

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
END
```

If I select all the procedure until the `begin try` and f5(execute it) it it gives no errors and I get the expected data on `@NewTempTable`; But when save the procedures and try to Execute it I get the following error

[image]

While `@NewTempTable` has the expected data, the execution of the procedure returns -6 and The data doesn't get inserted into `AlteracaoEngenharia.hComponents`.

None of the data I receive is null, neither are the `AlteracaoEngenharia.hComponents` columns not nullable.

I also have the same procedure in a TestServer exactly equal (some connections are different, but if that would be the mistake I would get no data) and that procedure works fine.

I know I'm not showing most of the procedure, buts it's a bit complex and with sensible information. I'm hoping I can get some pointers on the right direction with what I have described.

PS: I have tried with both `@newTempTable` and `##newTempTable`

Comment: If you have an error, you have a open transaction that nothing happens to as your `CATCH` is empty. You also completely disregard any errors, you don't `THROW` it, therefore knowing nothing about if your code fails or not.

Comment: Is it sql server you are using?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code / **errors** when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code bock:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
BEGIN TRY
 --DELETE OLD COMPONENTS
    Delete From AlteracaoEngenharia.hComponents where Id in
        (Select C.Id From AlteracaoEngenharia.hComponents as C
            Join AlteracaoEngenharia.hEngineeringChanges as EC on C.EngineeringChangeId = EC.Id
            Where C.Name not like '%(Manual)%' and EC.State like 'Aberto');

    Insert Into AlteracaoEngenharia.hComponents (Name, OldQuantity, Quantity, CDP, Value, Type, EngineeringChangeId)
        (Select Name, OldQuantity, Quantity, CDP, Value, Type, EngineeringChangeId From @NewTempTable);

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN   
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    throw;
    END 
END CATCH;
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN   
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    PRINT 'Successfully Completed'
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to ensure a full `ROLLBACK` after an error is to use `XACT_ABORT`, this forces all errors to abort the batch, and rollback the transaction:

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    --DELETE OLD COMPONENTS
    DELETE FROM AlteracaoEngenharia.hComponents 
    WHERE Id IN (SELECT C.Id  
                 FROM AlteracaoEngenharia.hComponents AS C
                 JOIN AlteracaoEngenharia.hEngineeringChanges AS EC ON C.EngineeringChangeId = EC.Id
                 WHERE C.Name NOT LIKE '%(Manual)%' AND EC.State LIKE 'Aberto');

    INSERT INTO AlteracaoEngenharia.hComponents (Name, OldQuantity, Quantity, CDP, Value, Type, EngineeringChangeId)
        (SELECT 
             Name, OldQuantity, Quantity, CDP, Value, Type, EngineeringChangeId 
         FROM 
             @NewTempTable);

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

No `TRY/CATCH` or `ROLLBACK` is necessary here, any error automatically rolls back.